# Hi. How can I Change the text of these fields in magento. midle name/Innitial

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I would like to know how to change the text like Middle Name or Firstname and lastname. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the template path hints and see the phtml file that is rendered on this section. Then you can go the rendered phtml file and change the field labels.

To turn on the template path hints, logon to admin panel and go to 
`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer Option -> Debug` and change the dropdown `Template Path Hints` value to Yes and save.

To know it in detail, follow the steps in the article [how to turn on the template path hints in magento](https://nikinpages.com/magento-admin-template-hints/)